# How do I monitor traffic between a Flash object and a server?

Tags: flash, firebug, monitoring, network-traffic

In Firebug's *Net* panel you can see all requests, which JavaScript is making to the server.

I would like to be able to do the same with a Flash object.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) fot this kind of debuging.

Comment: I've checked it out, and it doesn't seem to be better at snuffing out flash traffic than firebug is. I have compared the two using Zinga's facebook poker app, and none of those seems to be able to discern any requests related to the card combinations on the table

Comment: you're kidding right!? ... i would think that they're using https for communication like this.

Comment: even if you were to hack their encryption on the calls... I can say that the client side Flash does not get any information that would allow cheating.

Comment: I don't care about cheating. I'm just interested in reverse engineering flash objects